# Реализация разных компонентов с однаковыми стилями для mobile

Tags: css, reactjs, scss

Есть у нас разные компоненты постов, которые выглядят по разному на десктопной версии сайта.
(Изображения взяты для примера)

[image: Компонент 1 на desktop версии] [image: Компонент 2 на desktop версии][image: Компонент 3 на desktop версии]

Но на мобильной версии они все выглядят одинаково.

[image: Компонент для mobile версии]

И вот, чтобы эти разные версии карточек не стилизовать под один вид mobile, можем ли мы создать, например, div с class="desktop" и вложить туда структуру поста для десктопа и его стили. А ниже мы делаем div с class="mobile" и вложиваем туда отдельный компонент, который был создан специально со стилями для mobile. И когда у нас ширина экрана будет, припустим, меньше 768рх, то мы скрываем desktop и показываем mobile через display. Не будет ли проблем с оптимизацией в, если этих постов будет много или может есть какие то способы решения данной проблемы получше в react?